# Use modernizr to serve alternate background image for browsers without webgl support?

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, webgl, modernizr

I have a webgl animation in the background of my site and would like to offer some fallback support for browsers who don't have this feature. I want to serve an image in the background rather than the javascript file which creates the animation.

Modernizr offers some guidance and says to setup an `if...else` statement to activate the alternative option, like this:

```
if (Modernizr.webgl) {
  // supported
} else {
  // not-supported
}
```

They also suggest this css option:

```
.no-webgl body { background: red; }
```

Nether are working.

I don't want to put my animation script in the `if` statement and then something like this in the `else` statement:

```
var oldBrowserFix = document.getElementsByName("body");
oldBrowserFix.style.background = '#ff0000';
```

I also considered another idea:

```
do {
  var oldBrowserFix = document.getElementsByName("body");
  oldBrowserFix.style.background = '#ff0000';
} while (!Modernizr.webgl);
```

How can I get my `do...while` statement to work?

Comment: This might be a bug to bring up with the modernizr team on their GitHub.

Comment: in what browser is it not working? can you post a demo showing how it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add modernizr to bottom of html file and run this underneath it:

```
if (!Modernizr.webgl) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
}
```